Item selection probablity after sampling m items out of k and then sampling two item from the m items uniformly.
$m$ items are drawn from $[k] = {1,2,3,...., k}$ according to probability $q(i)$ iid with replacement. That is the probability of item $i$ being drawn is $q(i)$.
Then two items $x$ and $y$ are drawn from these $m$ items uniformly at random with replacement.
For any $i \in [k]$, is $P(x=i) = P(y=i) = q(i)$?
I simulated this scenario in Python and it seems like the above claim holds.
The proof attempt that I have is as follows:
P(x=i)
= P(In the second sampling, the first item from the m items is chosen ).(In the first sampling, the first of the m items is i) + ...... + P(In the second sampling, the last item from the m items is chosen ).(In the first sampling, the last of the m items is i) = $\sum_{i'=1}^{m} \frac{1}{m} q(i) = q(i)$.
Are the claim and the above approach correct? Thanks.

Let $X_1,X_2,\dots,X_m$ be the $m$ items; then $X_k$s are i.i.d. with $\mathbb{P}(X_k=j)=q(j)$. Let $\eta$ be the index of an item drawn from these $m$ objects,
then $\eta$ has a uniform distribution on $\{1,2,\dots,m\}$. Hence
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(X_\eta=i)&=\sum_{j=1}^m \mathbb{P}(X_\eta=i\mid \eta=j)\mathbb{P}(\eta=j)=\sum_{j=1}^m \mathbb{P}(X_j=i)\mathbb{P}(\eta=j)
\\ &=\sum_{j=1}^m q(i)\mathbb{P}(\eta=j)=q(i)\sum_{j=1}^m \mathbb{P}(\eta=j)=q(i).
\end{align}
